# Which 3rd party Oracle Database JDBC driver?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Which 3rd-party JDBC driver for Oracle Database is the most popular/preferred choice? (It is widely reported on the nets that Oracle's driver is buggy and lame.)

UPDATE: CORRECTION: Oracle's JDBC driver works fine for CLOB columns. The problems I was experiencing were with LONG columns. I have changed these to CLOB and now Oracle's driver works fine.

Comment: Why does it have to be 3rd-party?  The one Oracle supplies works OK, doesn't it?

Comment: it's buggy, lame, and doesn't support clobs well.

Comment: You could try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265690/whats-the-best-type-4-oracle-jdbc-driver

Comment: @Landon9720: can you prove that statement? I found the Oracle (thin) driver quite fast, stable and never had problems with CLOBs (at least not since the 10.x versions came out). Which version do you base your rant on?

Comment: Using Oracle's ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar with Hibernate.

Comment: I have also done a significant amount of work with LOBs without an issue.  I'm using ojdbc6 with an 11g DBMS.

Comment: We are running several large web applications (~100 page hits per second) that use CLOBs and BLOBs with the Oracle JDBC driver and never had problems. So I wonder what **exactly** your problems are

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and @JOTN are you using Hibernate? the problem I am having seems to be with the driver closing the connection after the first clob is read, meaning any additional reads will fail.

Comment: Some with Hibernate, some without, never a problem. Are you really talking about `CLOB` or are you maybe still using the `LONG` datatype? How do you retrieve the CLOB? Maybe you should post a more specific question regarding this

Comment: I would believe your code has issues not the JDBC driver. Maybe they had issues 10+ years ago, so did IBM's. Oracle has staked a lot on Java and I strongly doubt the driver is the issue.

Comment: Oracle driver is not a problem - I've used in production for many years and its fine. There are occasional bugs, but thats the same for anything. I'd just d/l the latest driver, and see what issues you have. Come back here when you have one, and somebody will help you aout.

Comment: Been using Oracle's drivers since 1997 with no problems.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you were dead_on. The problems I was having were with a LONG column that snuck into the schema. This has been changed to a CLOB and now Oracle's driver works fine.

Comment: LONG has been deprecated for a good reason back in the 80's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's CLOB support is fine. The LONG support is problematic. Updating the columns to CLOB fixed the problem. There is a lot of information on the net about bad CLOB support in Oracle's JDBC driver. This information is out of date.