# JDBC driver for oracle connectivity

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

currently i am using oracle version  10.2.0.3.0
and JDK 1.6.
and as a part of my requirement i need to read large files from database. (It should support reading LOBS and BLOBs etc)
please suggest me Which oracle driver i need to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any driver you can use. But Oracle thin Driver (Type 4) is better to use.

You can download it from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html)

Or otherwise if Oracle Enterprise Edition is installed in your system, then the **lib** folder must have the required jar files. The files are named as **ojdbc14.jar** or **classes12.jar**

Comment: Type 4 is ok for CLOB , but do see the issues faced by the particular person , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265690/whats-the-best-type-4-oracle-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 0):

Pom file :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```